# odometer jpgraph is not working in php

Tags: php, jpgraph

I want to show odometer simple example but its not working. My jpgraph files are within src/ directory. Myline graph is working but for odometer which file to use ??

PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once ('/src/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('/src/jpgraph_line.php');

require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_odo.php');

// Create a new odometer graph
$graph = new OdoGraph(500,180);

$odo = array();

// Now we need to create an odometer to add to the graph.
for( $i=0; $i < 5; ++$i ) {
    $odo[$i] = new Odometer();
    $odo[$i]->SetColor('lightgray:1.9');
    $odo[$i]->needle->Set(10+$i*17);
    $odo[$i]->needle->SetShadow();
    if( $i < 2 )
        $fsize = 10;
    else
        $fsize = 8;
    $odo[$i]->scale->label->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,$fsize);
    $odo[$i]->AddIndication(92,100,'red');
    $odo[$i]->AddIndication(80,92,'orange');
    $odo[$i]->AddIndication(60,80,'yellow');
}

// Create the layout
$row1 = new LayoutHor( array($odo[0],$odo[1]) );
$row2 = new LayoutHor( array($odo[2],$odo[3],$odo[4]) );
$col1 = new LayoutVert( array($row1,$row2) );

// Add the odometer to the graph
$graph->Add($col1);

// ... and finally stroke and stream the image back to the browser
$graph->Stroke();

?>
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'OdoGraph' not found in C:\wamp\www\PowerMonitor\odometer.php on line 9
```

Comment: Please clarify "not working"... is it giving an incorrect result? No output at all? An error code? ....?

Comment: not giving result at all i am updating error message.

Comment: Well its clearly says whats wrong.. it couldnt find the class which means either one of your `require_once` isnt loaded right or you missing the file that suppose to load this class

Comment: Maybe the `require_once()` should be `'/src/jpgraph_odo.php'` rather than `'jpgraph/jpgraph_odo.php'` to match the others? I guess all the jpgraph files are in the same folder?

Comment: no the problem is that where is jpgraph_odo.php. its not present in folder src where is this file ???

Comment: i sreached it alot but its neither present in jpgraph-3.5.0b1.tar.gz nor jpgraph-3.0.7.tar.gz downloaded from jpgraph official website. Is it present with another name??

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem of this Fatal error. As Gal pointed out, it is problem with in-proper JPGRAPH_ODO.PHP loading or missing. You can download the file from [here](http://code1.okbase.net/codefile/jpgraph_odo.php_2012122219082_263.htm) and keep it under src directory with other files. Then apply

```
require_once ('/src/jpgraph_odo.php');
```

might work.